# Impact of Changing an App Name on iTunes Connect

Tags: app-store-connect

I want to change the name of my app on iTunes when I release the next version, I know how to do this and am set to go but I am not sure what impact this might have on my app as it appears in the search results and leader boards/app ranking.

The original app name includes a brief description of the game. I want to remove the description and just leave the two-word app name which will be the same as before.

Are there any reasons I should avoid changing the app name?

Answer (score 0):

An app name is a great opportunity for an app marketer to get more "keyword space". Your keywords are limited to 100 characters, putting more "info" in the app name will get your app to appear on more searches (When the additional information in the app name doesn't match the keywords)

From a branding/design perspective, adding more info/words to the app name is not really "sexy". The rule of thumb here is to keep it short and simple (and recognizable).

So it really depends what your goal is. If the brief description has some really nice additional "keywords" in it, I would keep them, they will bring you search traffic.

Side note: We have different apps (~10), where we tried both short vs. long (= with description) app name and it brought us additional traffic, but the description has to have really good phrases in it. Therefore you can see it at the moment as additional space for keywords. (BTW: Same goes for In-App-Purchase Titles/Names: They are indexed like app names and can get you appear on additional search terms.)